# Is there any C/C++ system() function accepting unicode?

Tags: c++, c

Question: In C/C++, is there any system function that accepts Unicode ?
See below for reason:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313332/bringing-another-apps-window-to-front-on-mac-in-c
    system("osascript -e \"tell application \\\"Address Book\\\" to activate\"");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the reason. Can you explain?

Comment: Why the `linux` tag when the code in question clearly requires OS X to run?

Comment: What does the provided sample have to do with unicode?

Comment: Side note: You might want to check the return value of `system()` for being `0`, or `return EXIT_FAILURE` from your main-function. Only then the spawned executable has (apparently) completed successfully. You might never need that return value, but it is good style anyway.

Comment: @Nicholas Knight: Simple: What happens if instead of address book, the application title is "Адресная книга" or "通訊錄" (Russian/Chinese for "Address book") when the system function only accepts ASCII.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

system() does not care about the encoding as far as I know, it should just pass it through.

maybe your question is "how to type a UTF-8 string literal in C", or "what encoding does osascript expect"?

the portable way to do UTF-8 in C is with \x escape sequences, though if you are willing to rely on C99 or a specific compiler you can often type the UTF-8 directly.

I would guess osascript expects UTF-8 though I have no real idea.

Comment: Neither have I, I'm just swimming fixing an issue for OS X in a mono-Linux application.

Comment: if your actual code is just ASCII as you show in the example, of course, then there's no issue - I'm assuming the actual code is not ASCII

Comment: The actual code will be C#. I was just thinking about what happens if an application has not a title like "Address Book", but one like "Адресная книга" or "通訊錄".

Comment: ah OK. C# strings are defined to be in Unicode, right? so the only question is what encoding C# passes to the shell when you do a system(). you could just do something like system("echo Адресная книга > somefile.txt") and then see what you get in the file, perhaps.

Comment: Hm, on a second thought, I could just use Process.Start("osascript") and pass the parameters as startupinfo, and let C# that is to say the mono-team worry about the rest.

Answer (score 9):

Use `_wsystem`.

`_wsystem` is a wide-character version of `system`; the command argument to `_wsystem` is a wide-character string. These functions behave identically otherwise.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx

A special function named `main` is the starting point of execution for all C and C++ programs. If you are writing code that adheres to the Unicode programming model, you can use `wmain`, which is the wide-character version of main.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6wd819wh.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Standard C and C++ do not explicitly understand Unicode *at all*: none of the standard APIs are defined as accepting or returning Unicode strings. Unlike Java. Whether a *wide string* or *multibyte string* is actually a Unicode encoded string is system dependent. So the simple answer is *no*.

Comment: In this case though, it'd be suprising if system() (or the shell) somehow messed with the encoding before passing it to osascript. So the issue is what osascript wants. If osascript wants UTF-8, which seems likely, you just have to be sure the C string is in UTF-8, which can be done with \x escape sequences. The compiler is not going to mess with the bytes that you specify. It's true that system() is not defined to take any particular encoding (why would it even need to be?), but it doesn't matter here.