# Alternatives for c++ system() on linux

Tags: c++, unicode

I am trying to execute some scripts from within my C++ program using `system()` command. I am aware of cons of using system to execute something outside current execution.

My problem is, I can do a `system(path)` where `path` refers to the shell script that I need to execute. I am trying to work with unicode now and my path can contain japanese/chinese etc characters. I made my path char16_t to use UTF16 encoding, but how do I call the system() now??

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Can the shell handle UTF-8 paths normally? Then just use UTF-8 strings.

Comment: Isn't the terminal (the shell sh) operating with UTF8?

Comment: What about using [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call ? But it will not **portable** as UNIX specific.

Comment: this is just a part of someting major. I get the path as UTF16 char16_t * and need to work with it. So looking for alternatives with this. I already looked at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419493/is-there-any-c-c-system-function-accepting-unicode but  was not entirely sure how to work with it

Comment: @Raito: Why would `execve` deal with Unicode better than `system()`?

Comment: @KeithThompson My bad, didn't see that it needed special encoding.

Comment: This is likely impossible to answer without knowing what operating system you're using? How are these Japanese/Chinese paths actually encoded in the file system? If you're using a UNIX-like system (including Linux), it probably doesn't use UTF-16 by default. Why are you using UTF-16? (Windows uses UTF-16 / UCS-2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to the encoding expected by the shell (probably UTF-8, and probably using the iconv library).
Then call `system()` with it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convert the utf16 to utf8 and then use system or fork and execv.

Comment: A *cast* isn't going to convert utf-16 to utf-8.

Comment: When I said "cast" I didn't mean c++'s cast. I meant maybe he can use utf8 instead (which I think supports Japanese) .

Comment: Then I suggest using a word other than "cast", which has a very specific meaning. *Convert* would work.